# How to fix "Express is not a constructor" Type Error when you deploy your app to heroku but app can't start?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have deployed an app to heroku but it can't start because of the type error "express is not a constructor" in my index.js file.
Files can be found in https://github.com/Wachiye/blog.git

Comment: Please embed the relevant code in the question instead of directing us to a project link

Answer (score 1):

Express is just a factory function, not a constructor.  So, you don't use `new` with.  You would use it like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

Shown right here in [the doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app).

In the future, please embed the relevant code portion into your question and format it appropriately.  Stackoverflow has a whole bunch of reasons for wanting you to do it that way AND it will get you a faster answer.  You get answers here faster when YOU make the question quick and easy to understand without going to external resources.

Comment: I tried this out and am getting the error message "Express is not a function"

Comment: @Wachiye - What exact line of code generates that error?  Please show that line of code and any others surrounding it needed for appropriate context.  What is the EXACT error message you get?  Are you sure that the express module is installed properly?